# Calling printText method from Gui class from anoter class

Tags: java, swing, singleton, stack-overflow

I am trying to implement a singleton into my GUI class but once i return the instance it gives me a nullpointer exception, i have been looking at multiple sources but it just doesnt work right.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Write a description of class GUI here.
 */
public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("VoidWorld");
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(10, 45);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
    JTextArea textAreaSide = new JTextArea(10, 15);
    JScrollPane scrollPaneSide = new JScrollPane(textAreaSide);
    JTextField textfield = new JTextField("", 5);
    Color bgcolor = new Color(255, 255, 255);

    private static GUI instance;

    Parser command;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GUI
     */
    private GUI()
    {
        command = new Parser();

        textarea.setEditable(false);
        frame.setSize(900,400);

        frame.add(scrollPaneSide, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textAreaSide.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        textAreaSide.setForeground(Color.red);
        textAreaSide.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));
        textAreaSide.setBackground(bgcolor);
        textAreaSide.setLineWrap(true);

        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        textarea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        textarea.setForeground(Color.black);
        textarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));
        textarea.setBackground(bgcolor);
        textarea.setLineWrap(true);

        frame.add(textfield, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        textfield.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        textfield.setForeground(Color.black);
        textfield.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white));
        textfield.setBackground(bgcolor);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        textfield.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
                public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                    printIfTextFieldIsActivated(evt);
                }
            });
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new GUI();
                }
            });
    }

    private void printIfTextFieldIsActivated(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            String commandString = textfield.getText().toString();
            String output = command.parseCommand(commandString);
            printAppend(output);
            textfield.setText("");
        }
    } 

    public static GUI getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new GUI();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

When i call getInstance from another class it will give me a stackoverflow, since instance is always null, i know my GUI class is created because i can see the Gui.

Thanks,

p.s. Sorry for messy code im not an expert on this..

Comment: Before I get to your actual problem, a number of things jump out at me. `GUI` extends from `JFrame`, but you create a second `JFrame` in it's constructor - I now have no idea which frame is been used for what.  As a general rule, you should avoid extending from `JFrame` (if for nothing else, because of this kind of issue). You should void using `KeyListener` and text components, in your case a `ActionListener` will do the same job, more simply. You're also missing the implementation of `printAppend` which may or may not be an issue

Comment: Your implementation of a singleton is problematic and could leak multiple instances

Comment: So I took your code, modified so it would run and had no issues.  You might consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things come to mind:

1. You need to instantiate the `GUI` through the `getInstance()` method:

   `public void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   new GUI()           // <-- NO
                   GUI.getInstance();  // <-- YES
               }
           });
   }`
2. You may be accessing the `instance` field from different threads. If so, marking it as `volatile` may help. Like this: `private static volatile GUI instance;`
3. You may be triggering a listener in the `GUI` constructor which tries to get the instance through `GUI.getInstance()` before the constructor is finished.

Comment: Since `GUI`s constructor is private; `private GUI()`, they wouldn't be able to insatiate the class via `new`

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right, but he is doing it in his code. That is why I told him not to do it.

Comment: Where are they doing it their code?  I don't see it the code they've provided and since it would generate a compiler error, I don't see how it's either possible or relevant

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is in his `main` method, which is inside his `GUI` class, which makes the private constructor accessible to it.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, missed that, my bad :P